# How to command scripts in cronjob file and how to creat it

Tags: cron

I'm confused with Cronjob, my posts are not going to Google and I don't know how to set them up, I'm asking for help very quickly
This issue has been very difficult for me, so I am asking you to help me, it is really bothering me

Comment: Explain your problem (do not add all in headline!)

Comment: Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. It may be helpful to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).